# Are these sentences the examples of Transitive, Ditransitive and Complex Transitives Verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs, ditransitive-verbs, lexical-verbs

He goes to school or he goto school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transitive verb has an object.  The verb "leave" can be used as a transitive verb in the first case the object is "him".

A different sense of the verb "leave" is "give a gift to someone in a will" This is the ditransitive sense in 2.  John's father gave John a theatre in John's fathers will.

Number three is just transitive, with a prepositional phrase. This prepositional phrase is an optional adjunct.

Complex transitive verbs have a direct object and an object complement, which can be a noun phrase or an adjective.

> She painted the barn green.

> The class unanimously elected her student president.

(Ditransitive verbs are a type of complex transitive)

So it might be possible to say

> John left his father happy.

And there is also an intransitive form:

> John left.

Note that in these case, the meaning of "leave" is different from either your examples 1 or 2.  Generally the meaning of a verb depends on whether its intransitive, transitive or complex transitive form is being used.

Comment: So we can that the (1) is transitive and (2) is ditransitive?